# DeliveryReceipt for message is null

Tags: java, sms, smpp, jsmpp

I'm using the `JSMPP` SMPP library for sending SMS to mobile numbers which is running successfully but `deliverSm.getShortMessage()` and `deliverSm.getShortMessageAsDeliveryReceipt` are NULL -- that is, I am not able to receive `deliveryReceipt`.

Connection is set as `TRX`. I have set my Registered Delivery like this:

```
RegisteredDelivery registeredDelivery = new RegisteredDelivery();
registeredDelivery.setSMSCDeliveryReceipt(SMSCDeliveryReceipt.SUCCESS_FAILURE);
registeredDelivery.setSMEOriginatedAcknowledgement(SMEOriginatedAcknowledgement.DELIVERY_MANUAL);
```

and I am also getting `deliver_sm.getemsclass` as `4`.

I would appreciate if someone could help me with because i have been stuck for quite a while now.
Thanks!